# What does it mean to take the first Chern class of a sheaf?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I know that if I have a divisor $D$ on a Riemann surface $X$, there is a line bundle associated to $D$, that I write as $[D]$ following the terminology in Griffiths & Harris (Principles of Algebraic Geometry). Now I know that the expression $c_1([D])$ makes sense, as $c_1$ associates an element of $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}^*)\cong \textrm{Pic}(X)$ to a class in $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$. However in reading about the Hirzebruch-Riemann-Roch theorem, I saw the following assertion: $$\int_Xc_1(\mathcal{O}(D))=\deg(D),$$ where I think $\mathcal{O}(D)$ is the sheaf of holomorphic sections of the associated line bundle $[D]$.

How am I supposed to understand $c_1(\mathcal{O}(D))$ since $\mathcal{O}(D)$ is a sheaf and not a line bundle (albeit it is a sheaf associated to a line bundle)?

EDIT: If $s$ is a meromorphic section of a line bundle $L$, then the fact is that $[(s)]=L$ where $(s)$ is the divisor of the section, i.e. $$(s)=\sum_{p\in X}\textrm{ord}_p(s)\cdot p.$$
Therefore for any such section $s$ of $\mathcal{O}([D])$ I just take $[(s)]=[D]$ and $c_1(\mathcal{O}(D))$ must be taken to mean $c_1([D])$. Can someone confirm this?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Lots of algebraic geometers "confuse" $\mathscr O(L)$ and $L$ and use them interchangeably. In fact, one *can* define Chern classes much more generally, for coherent sheaves on algebraic manifolds, in terms of resolutions by vector bundles. See Appendix I of Hirzebruch's *Topological Methods in Algebraic Geometry*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all correct!

Generally speaking, there's a mismatch with the definitions some people immediately latch to when hearing/using the words 'line-bundle'. The 'algebraic geometry' way to define a line bundle $\mathcal{L}$ on a variety $X/\mathbf{C}$ is as a sheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules which is locally (either in $X$'s analytic or Zariski topology, if it's algebraic - this ends up not mattering if $X$ is compact for instance by a theorem of Serre) isomorphic to the free rank-one $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. From such sheaves [one can then contruct](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01M1) (very algebraically) an actual line bundle $L \to X$ called the 'geometric vector bundle associated to the sheaf $\mathcal{L}$' and this produces an equivalence between the two notions. Moreover and crucially for your question, because this equivalence is functorial in $X$, any open subset on which the sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{O}_X$ is also an open on which the line bundle $L \to X$ restrict to a product of a one-dimentional vector space with the base *and viceversa*: the gluing data for $L$ and $\mathcal{L}$ provide the same Cech cocycle in the sheaf cohomology group $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ and thus the abuse of notation $c_1(L) = c_1(\mathcal{L})$ is justified.